# Using Google Docs API spreadsheet as Ember Data-Store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to be able to create a pretty dead simple Ember.js application and have it populate a Google Spreadsheet, and also have the capability to go back and edit records. Is this even feasible? Does anybody know of a good tutorial, github repo or gist demonstrating this?

Right now it is just an idea, and searching the web did not yield much. Is this because it is a foolish idea, or just because nobody has done it yet?

Comment: Hey @knu2xs. Any luck with this?  I was interested in using Google Drive (sheets, fusion tables, etc.) as a data store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is: [ember-gdrive](https://github.com/coderly/ember-gdrive)
provides ember data bindings for google drive.